# Cap option on Libor

Tags: options, fixed-income, bond, derivatives

We denote `discount factor` $D(t),$ `zero coupon bond` $B(t,T),$ $E_t[X] = E[X|\mathcal{F}(t)]$ and $T$-forward measure $E_t^{T}[\ ].$

First, let me fix the `Libor` and `Forward Libor` to avoid ambiguity

`Libor` $L(t,T):$
$$B(t, T)\cdot \Big(1 + (T-t) L(t, T)\Big) = 1.$$
`Forward Libor` $F(t,T-\delta,T):$
$$\Big(1 + (T-t)F(t,T-\delta,T)\Big)B(t,T) = B(t,T-\delta)$$

Now we see the `cap`
$$C(t;T,L^*) = \dfrac{1}{D(t)}E_t\left[D(T)\delta\Big(F(t,T-\delta,T) - L^*\Big)^+\right]$$
We can change into forward measure
$$C(t;T,L^*) = \delta B(t,T)E^T_t\left[\Big(F(t,T-\delta,T) - L^*\Big)^+\right]$$
and $F(t,T-\delta,T)$ is $T$-forward martingale, the above formula become the standard `Black-Scholes.`

But if we choose
$$C(t;T,L^*) = \dfrac{1}{D(t)}E_t\left[D(T)\delta\Big(L(T-\delta,T) - L^*\Big)^+\right]$$
then we can transform into
$$C(t;T,L^*) = (1+\delta L^*)\cdot E^{T}_{t}\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\delta L^*} - B(T-\delta,T)\right)^+\right]$$
it become a bond put option expiring at time $T - \delta$ maturing at time $T.$

But $B(t,T)$ is impossible `log-normal` under $T$-forward measure, then we can't use `Black-Scholes.` So how to deal with for this case?

Comment: As you said, the bond price $B(t,T)$ will certainly not follow Black-Scholes dynamics. However, the forward Libor could.
Therefore, it depends on what you want to do. If you want to price, you can use Black-76 formula to price the cap from your formula $C(t;T,L^*) = \delta B(t,T) E^T_t \left[ \left( F(t,T-\delta,T) - L^*\right)^+ \right]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
&\ \dfrac{1}{D(t)}E_t\left(D(T)\delta\Big(L(T-\delta,T) - L^*\Big)^+\right)\\
=&\ \dfrac{1}{D(t)}E\left(D(T-\delta) E\left(\frac{D(T)}{D(T-\delta)}\delta\Big(L(T-\delta,T) - L^*\Big)^+\mid\mathcal{F}_{T-\delta}\right)  \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
=&\ \dfrac{1}{D(t)}E\left(D(T-\delta) B(T-\delta, T)\delta\Big(L(T-\delta,T) - L^*\Big)^+\mid\mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
=&\ (1+\delta L^*)\dfrac{1}{D(t)}E\left(D(T-\delta)\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\delta L^*} - B(T-\delta,T) \right)^+\mid\mathcal{F}_t\right)\tag{1}\\
=&\ (1+\delta L^*)B(t, T)E^T_t\left(\frac{D(T-\delta)}{D(T)}\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\delta L^*} - B(T-\delta,T) \right)^+\right).
\end{align*}
Your transformation from
$$C(t;T,L^*) = \dfrac{1}{D(t)}E_t\left(D(T)\delta\Big(L(T-\delta,T) - L^*\Big)^+\right)$$
to
$$C(t;T,L^*) = (1+\delta L^*)\cdot E^{T}_{t}\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\delta L^*} - B(T-\delta,T)\right)^+\right)$$
does not appear correct.

We also note that $(1)$ is indeed the value of a put bond option with maturity $T-\delta$. Based on a certain short rate model such as the Hull-White model, this value can be computed analytically.