# Hull-White calibration volatility as a function of time

Tags: options, calibration, hullwhite

I need some help for the parametrization of the volatility parameter in the Hull-White model.

I have the necessary Caplet vols and I calibrated the HW model to match the Caplet and hence the Cap prices exactly.

But I calibrated the volatility as one factor for every Caplet. I didn't parametrize the volatility as a function of time for each T.

That could be the reason why my volatility is always higher than the volatility of the previous Caplet. I do not get a proper volatility term structure that is consistent with the market volatility structure, though my prices fit exactly.

I posted already something here: [Cap price as bond options](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49141/cap-price-as-bond-options)

The topic was a different (more fundamental) one, but the answer I am refering now to is that:

> Hull-White calibration on cap volatilities The first step is to strip
>   caps vol to get caplet vols. See for example:
>   http://www.smileofthales.com/financial/cap-floor-pricing-stripping-the-basics/
>
> Let's suppose you want to calibration on caplets with expiries
>   T1
>
> You start with the option with the nearest expiry T1, then determine
>   the volatility σ(T1) that enables you to match the T1 caplets price.
>
> Then, you move on to T2, the caplet price is a function of σ(T1) that
>   is already known and σ(T2), so you determine the value of σ(T2)
>   enabling you to match the T2 and so on, until you get to Tn, and you
>   are done.

In the Hull-White paper from 2000 they provide this information about calibrating the vol parameter:
[image]

Now I am kind of confused.

1) How do I set up the parametrized volatility function and what do I calibrate for? For the time parameter or the other two parameters?

[image]
2) This would yield in always same parameters and just the Time is changing? Do i then calibrate the T?

3) What are the corner points in time? I want to calibrate to each Caplet. Are my T the points in time for the Caplets? Starting with 0.5 for the first Caplet (6month tenor) and then going on to 1 - 1.5 - 2.0 - 2.5 and so on until every Caplet is calibrated?

I am really confused and would appreciate If some could serve me a fundamental great answer about the parametrization.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Christian. If you choose a piecewise-constant Hull-White volatility function, with as many points as the expiries of the caplets you are trying to calibrate to, then you can do the bootstrap procedure described in the answer you are referring to.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I didn't bootstrap the Caplet volatilities on my own. How do I proceed with calibrating the Hull-White volatilities as a function of time?

Comment: Let's suppose you have 3 caplets to simplify, with expirires $0 < T_1 < T_2 < T_3$. You have the caplet's price as a function of $\sigma_1$ = HW vol on the interval $[0, T_1]$, so you determine the vol that enables you to match the caplet's price. Then you move on to the next, i.e. $T_2$, the caplet's price now is a function of $\sigma_1$ (already calibrated) as well as $\sigma_2$ = HW vol on the interval $]T_1, T_2]$, so you determine the value that gives you the market's price. Then you do the same thing for $T_3$. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: But why is the second Caplet's price a function of σ1? How do I  do that? I first calibrate the single volatility to match the first Caplet's price. Than I Calibrate the single volatility to the second Caplet's price and so on. But how do I calibrate the volatilities that they depend on each other. I would appreciate if you could explain me the function a bit more. And do I just calibrate the single volatility parameter for each time interval or do I need to parametrize the function as posted in the screenshots from Hull-White (2000)?

Comment: The other question establishes that the caplet's price with expiry $T_2$ is given by Black's formula with a vol given by:
$$\begin{aligned}
\Sigma^2(0,T_2)&=B(T_2,T_2+\delta)^2\int_0^{T_2}e^{-2a(T_2-u)}\sigma^2(u)du \\&=B(T_2,T_2+\delta)^2 \left[\int_0^{T_1}e^{-2a(T_2-u)}\sigma^2(u) du+\int_{T_1}^{T_2}e^{-2a(T_2-u)}\sigma^2(u)du\right]\\
&=B(T_2,T_2+\delta)^2\left[\sigma_1^2\int_0^{T_1}e^{-2a(T_2-u)}du+\sigma_2^2\int_{T_1}^{T_2}e^{-2a(T_2-u)}du\right]
\end{aligned}$$
at this stage, only $\sigma_2$ is unknown. It can be computed by equating: $\Sigma_{HW}(0,T_2)=\Sigma_\text{market}(0,T_2)$

Comment: Next, you move on to $T_3$ and so on... 
At the end, you get your Hull-White volatility term structure, which is piecewise-constant on each $]T_{i-1}, T_i], i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.
I hope it is clear now.

Comment: So to summarize: since I already have the whole market volatility term structure from Blacks model (Σmarket(0,T)) for every piecewise-constant T, I just need to calibrate my Hull-White Caplet price to each Black Caplets' price, right? I use a solver for this optimization problem and use the analytical Hull-White formula and setting a between a range of 0.01 and 0.05.

Comment: Exactly, you have to do a minimization at each step $k$ in order to determine the HW volatility $\sigma_k$ for the interval $]T_{k-1}, T_k]$. I hope this is clear. You can reprice the calibration basket once you are done to ensure that everything went well :) One last question for you, how do you plan to determine the mean reversion? Do you input it manually?

Comment: Thank you! What do you exactly mean by reprice the basket? Sadly, my HW volatility term structure is different from the one that I obtain from Black Caplet volatilities. Is this normal? I determine the mean reversion by trying experimentally what mean reversion parameter fits my optimization the best.

Comment: You have a HW vol, which is piecewise constant. Then you have the Black vol used to price the caplets, which is a function of the HW vol. The Black vol is observed in the market (input) and the aim of the calibration is to determine the value of HW vol that enables to match it for various instruments (caplets with expiries $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_n$). The calibration is a minimization of the difference between the Black vol given by the HW model vs. the market, so once you are done, you can compute the Black vols given by the HW model for your caplets to ensure that they are close to the market's.

Comment: As for the mean reversion, you can either choose a value and input it manually, or do a first step (before the bootstrap calibration explained above), where you suppose that your HW vol is constant and where you determine the mean reversion and constant HW vol that minimize the sum of squared errors accross all your caplets. Then you keep the mean reversion throw away the constnat vol value, and determine the HW vol term structure by the bootstrap procedure explained above. I hope it's clear :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice with the mean reversion parameter! Yes, I guess it is all clear if you mean the HW implied volatility by "compute the Black vols given by the HW model". Thank you !

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant :) I'll try to summarise the various points from the comment into a proper answer. Cheers.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. My mistake was to not have a look at the implied (!) volatility of the Hull-White model and just compare the "calibrated" volatility parameters with the Black implied volatility structure.

Comment: I posted the answer, let me know if anything is still unclear ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the question you are referring to, we have established that the caplet has a closed-form formula under Hull-White model, with the Black implied volatility $\Sigma$ a function of the Hull-White volatility $\sigma$ term structure from 0 and until the caplet's expiry $T$:
$$
\Sigma^2(0,T)=B(T,T+\delta)^2\int_0^T e^{−2a(T−u)}\sigma^2(u)du
$$

To calibrate on a basket of caplets, with expiries $0 < T_1 < T_2 < \dots < T_n$, you can choose a piecewise-constant term structure for the Hull-White volatility, with pillars corresponding to these expiries $(T_i)_i$. That is:
$$
\sigma(t) = \sigma_i, \quad T_{i-1} < t \leq T_i
$$

In this case, you can use a bootstrap procedure to calibrate each value $\sigma_i$ on a calibration instrument. In the first step, only $\sigma_1$ is unknown, and you solve for it:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Sigma^2_\text{market}(0, T_1) &= \Sigma^2(0, T_1) \\
&= B(T_1, T_1 + \delta)^2 \sigma_1^2 \int_0^{T_1} e^{-2a(T_1 - u)}du
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, you move on to $T_2$, and solve for $\sigma_2$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Sigma^2(0,T_2)_\text{market} &= \Sigma^2(0,T_2)\\
&=B(T_2,T_2+\delta)^2\left[\int_0^{T_1}e^{−2a(T_2−u)}\sigma^2(u)du+\int_{T_1}^{T_2}e^{−2a(T_2−u)}\sigma^2(u)du \right] \\
&=B(T_2,T_2+\delta)^2 \left[\sigma^2_1 \int_0^{T_1}e^{−2a(T_2−u)}du+\sigma^2_2 \int_{T_1}^{T_2}e^{−2a(T_2−u)}du \right]
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on...

But what about the mean-reversion?

It depends on what you want to use your Hull-While calibrated model for, but two possibilities come to mind:

- Input a mean reversion value (determined for example statistically from the observation of rates time-series, or using macro-economic reasoning, etc.);
- or, Before doing the routine above, consider the volatility constant and calibrate the mean-reversion and constant vol that minimize the sum of squared errors accross all your calibration basket. Then use this mean-reversion in the bootstrap routine described above.